# Eliminate duplicate data

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

#### Query

```
SELECT
  ppc.personid,
  ppc.category,
  ppc.phonenumber,
  ppc.createts
FROM
  person_phone_contacts ppc
WHERE  
      CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN ppc.createts AND ppc.endts
  AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN ppc.effectivedate AND ppc.enddate
ORDER BY
  ppc.personid, ppc.category, ppc.createts DESC
```

#### Resulting Data

```
3742 | Home   | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-09-09 11:59:00.357-04
3742 | Home   | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-08-04 20:13:17.161-04*
3742 | Mobile | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-09-09 11:59:20.070-04
3742 | Mobile | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-09-09 11:59:20.070-04*
3742 | Other  | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-08-04 20:13:17.161-04
```

<sup>*</sup>Desired duplicates to discard.

#### Desired Data

```
3742 | Home   | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-09-09 11:59:00.357-04
3742 | Mobile | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-09-09 11:59:20.070-04
3742 | Other  | xxx-xxx-xxxx | 2009-08-04 20:13:17.161-04
```

#### Question

What is the most efficient way to retrieve a single phone number per category per person, using the most recent date (even when multiple phone numbers in the same category for the same person have the same date)?

#### Possible Solutions

Use `DISTINCT ON (ppc.category) category` can limit the results per person, but how to apply it to all people, individually?

#### Constraints

- PostgreSQL 8.3
- No stored functions or procedures

Thank you!

Comment: [Simulating ROW_NUMBER in PostgreSQL, Pre 8.4](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/79-Simulating-Row-Number-in-PostgreSQL-Pre-8.4.html)

Comment: too bad you're not on 8.4 w/ windowing functions :-(

Comment: @Adam: Yes, I wish I could use 8.4, but the production database is 8.3.

Comment: @Dave: Ponies' link should help, then. What *doesn't* that guy know?

Comment: @Adam: It looks like the query that takes the `COALESCE` form will be too slow (creating a temporary table is out of the question--I have to take the results from this query and create a crosstab to get the final answer). The data set is 100,000 strong and growing.

Comment: Is there any chance of an upgrade?  v9 was just released...  Smaller the data set, better the time to do it.

Comment: Definitely too slow. Over 60 seconds to run the query, and counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that (personid, category, createts) is unique...

```
SELECT
  ppc.personid,
  ppc.category,
  ppc.phonenumber,
  ppc.createts
FROM
  person_phone_contacts AS ppc
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      personid,
      category,
      MAX(createts) AS newest_createts
    FROM
      person_phone_contacts
    WHERE  
          CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN createts AND endts
      AND CURRENT_DATE BETWEEN effectivedate AND enddate
    GROUP BY
      personid, category
  ) AS ppc2
  ON ppc.personid = ppc2.personid
    AND ppc.category = ppc2.category
    AND ppc.createts = ppc2.newest_createts
```

I'm not familiar with Postgres' SQL dialect (using MSSQL myself, where this could be solved more elegantly), but since this is pretty much standard SQL I think it should work.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Runs in 8 seconds.

Comment: Which I would consider slow for a table with "just" 100k rows :) If you don't have an index on createts yet, make one. Might speed up the JOIN considerable, maybe even the WHERE clause.